# There's an error in my num_rows, but I can't see it

Tags: php, mysqli, count

OK, so I've gone round and round so many times now, I probably can't see the wood for the trees.

I want to return the number of rows that match the WHERE clause.  This is my code

```
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title, category, last_completed, next_due, assigned_to FROM activities WHERE userId = ? AND status = ? AND DATEDIFF('$date', next_due) >= 1");
          $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userId, $status);
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
          $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
          echo $num_rows;
```

I have no doubt the error is obvious, but I can't see it.  I can return the number of rows and establish it is more than 0, I just can't echo the num_rows!!!!

Comment: `mysql_` can't be used with `mysqli_` - Use `$stmt->num_rows;` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection is oops method. so do with `Oops` format  see the difference https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
$conn->num_rows
```